# Random click button

Tags: python, selenium

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="_1OSdk">
          <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL    KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui già</button>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

so this code display a list of buttons, i need a code that let me click from the last button to the first button, in the code that i wrote i found the buttons by css_selector that it's equal for all the buttons.
The code that i wrote goes good but it click from the first button to the last button and i don't know how to invert this.

The code that i wrote is this

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    while a==0 :
    try:
        #GO TO THE BOTTOM OF THE TABLE
        driver.find_element_by_xpath ("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div").click ()
        elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector (".j6cq2")
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        time.sleep (2)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        time.sleep (2)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        time.sleep (2)

        #SEARCH FOR THE BUTTON THAT IT HAS TO CLICK
        Segui_Già = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._5f5mN.-fzfL.KUBKM.yZn4P")

        #IF THE BUTTON IT'S NOT FOUND IT SCROLL UP THE TABLE
    except NoSuchElementException :
        driver.find_element_by_xpath ("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div").click ()
        elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector (".j6cq2")
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_UP)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_UP)

        #IF THE BUTTON IT'S FOUND IT CLICKS THE THE FIRST BUTTON THAT HE FOUNDS
    else:
        Segui_Già.click()
        a=a+1
        print(a)
        time.sleep(5)
```

i have a table with all this buttons displayed and i need that the code click from the last button to the first.
This code click from the first button to the last so the reverse of what i need.
(On the site where i have to run this code when a button it's clicked it changes the css_selector so the code that i wrote doesn't stop on the first element for this)

Comment: Your question makes no sense, please elaborate appropriately. Also, please format your code to an actual readable format with proper indents and line-space.

Comment: ok sry i edited now

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet which adds an onclick-event to each of your buttons. If clicked, the script will check how many buttons are behind the clicked one and returns the number within an alert.
I actually don't know how you're using Python within JS, therefore I used only plain old JS.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Syndesi/9wh0rvn7/)

```
// code from the fiddle
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('KUBKM');
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e){
        var li = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        var i = 0;
        while(li != null){
            li = li.nextSibling;
            if(li != null){
                if(li.tagName == 'LI'){
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        //console.log('Button '+i+' was clicked');
        alert('Button '+i+' was clicked');
    }
}
```

Comment: sry i'm not rly good, i'm new in creating codes, so i saw what u created and it's near what i wanted, how i can automate this? i need that the code take the list fo the buttons and after click from the last button to the first

Comment: No problem, everybody has started somewhere ;)
But what do you actually want to do? Change the direction of the buttons from A-B-C to C-B-A?

Comment: Thanks bro :). Yes i need that the code click from the last one to the first so not A-B-C but  C-B-A

Comment: The current script changes now the buttons from A-B-C to C-B-A and vice-versa: https://jsfiddle.net/Syndesi/14nyku1v/

Comment: If it's not the thing you wanted, pls write more about your case (e.g. what do you want to do with it? what changes exactly? should every button get another id? ...)

Comment: ok so if i understood , when i automate this by `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._5f5mN.-fzfL.KUBKM.yZn4P").click()` it click the last one for first. But i don't know how to put this code in my python file

Comment: The problem here is that you didn't posted any details to your python-program (e.g. used librarys and your code). Without these informations I can't help you :/

Answer (score 0):

now I understand your question: You're trying to get these buttons and click them from the last one until the first one is reached.
I think this snippet should work:

```
#SEARCH FOR THE BUTTON THAT IT HAS TO CLICK

for button in reversed(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._5f5mN.-fzfL.KUBKM.yZn4P")):
    button.click()
    time.sleep(5)

# and the else-clause shouldn't be needed anymore
```

Comment: loving you , didn't know the existence of "reverse" thanks a lot :D it works fine

Comment: No problem :) But please post next time all relevant code, so that we can solve the real problem ;)

Comment: ye i will :) .just another thing how i can stop the loop after that it ran the first time ? i tried to add `break` at the end of the cod but it doesn't work. so i need that it starts , it clicks the first button, and after it stops

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._5f5mN.-fzfL.KUBKM.yZn4P")[-1].click()`

Comment: `break` should normally work, but if you just need to click the last button then the previously posted code should work fine.